# IBM RFT : Cannot add Firefox as browser

Tags: firefox, rft

On windows, I am trying to Add Firefox (57.0.2) as a browser in RFT(9.1).

When I click on Configure -> Enable Environment for testing -> Web Browser -> Add and choose C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox I get the following message:

The [C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox] file is not the specified directory for an installed browser.

But it is the installation directory. firefox.exe and all the other files (mostly dll) are inside it.

If I copy iexplore.exe inside that Mozilla Firefox directory, I can then add it and change the iexplore command to firefox and am able to save it as a browser. But in that case, the browser 'Kind' is IE and I get a bunch of exception when trying to execute. Also, if I rename firefox.exe for 'chrome.exe' then I am able to add it and the 'Kind' changes to Chrome.

Any idea why RFT don't recognize C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox as a browser installation folder? I wonder how RFT detects if it's Firefox or not..it's weird that by renaming 'firefox.exe' for 'chrome.exe' it's saving it as a Chrome browser but firefox.exe isn't working.

Comment: Does this help: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22000301 ?

Comment: omg..How did you find this, I've been googling this since yesterday (and usually I'm good at googling!) THANKS!

Comment: Search for `rft firefox`, second result

Comment: Not on my side....but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM has a support document, that mentions Firefox 50: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22000301

Basically, you need to add a folder inside the Firefox Installation Path:

> 3. Open Windows Explorer and go to \browser. For example,C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser.
> 4. Create a new folder called **components**.